# How does lex/flex compress its DFA table?

Tags: c, lex

There are yy_base, yy_meta, and other tables which are generated by flex. How do they work?

Comment: [Flex is open-source](https://github.com/westes/flex). You can check its source to see what it does.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude You could answer 99% of the questions here this way ;)